# crash_dump helper failed to exec, or was killed in android 13 realme

Tags: android-studio, android-13

I found this issue in only android 13 Realme phone.
App is getting close on the activity.
below is the statement what I have found in the Android Studio Logcat.
"crash_dump helper failed to exec, or was killed"

I have searched the different solutions on the google. But none of the solutions are working in this regard.
I also searched for update of this specific version of OS UI. but found none interesting.
Same question is there on Realme community Forum.
Please suggest whom to approach to solve it finally. Either to use any specific tool or to use any specific library ??